# Html, css верстка

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование

Есть верстка следующего вида:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="block">
      <h3 class="title>a</h3>
      <p class="description>bb</p>
   </div>

   <div class="block">
      <h3 class="title>aa</h3>
      <p class="description>bbbb</p>
   </div>

   <div class="block">
      <h3 class="title>aaa</h3>
      <p class="description>bbbbbb</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать такой вывод используя только html и css, не задавая размеры:

```
a
b
b
aa
bb
bb
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
```

Если описывать словами, то размер `description` должен быть равен размеру `title`.

То есть, `description` должен подстраиваться под размер `title`, и если что, то переносить слова на новую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для [современных](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) браузеров можно так:

```css
.block {
  width: min-content;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.description {
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">a</h3>
    <p class="description">bb</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">aa</h3>
    <p class="description">bbbb</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">aaa</h3>
    <p class="description">bbbbbb</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ооо бро пасиб. Выручил.

Answer (score 1):

Может есть и другой вариант, но этот вроде рабочий.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: min-content;
}

.title,
.description {
  margin: 0;
}

.title {
  width: max-content;
}

.description {
  word-wrap: anywhere;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">a</h3>
    <p class="description">bb</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">aa</h3>
    <p class="description">bbbb</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">aaa</h3>
    <p class="description">bbbbbb</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h3>
    <p class="description">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3 class="title">aaaa</h3>
    <p class="description">bbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если ставите минус, пишите в комментариях почему. Иначе вы как пустослов..

Comment: +)  Оригинально.

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно было. Имелось ввиду то что description должен подстраиваться под размер title, и если что переносить слова на новую строку

Comment: @Vilia, по факту это и есть перенос на новую строку. Если нужен перенос аля `<br>` или `\n`, то тут уже средствами JS\JQ

Comment: Эм.. Это ж вообще на то, что требуется в вопросе, не похоже...